# Change form option to Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I use in my project Laravel 7 and https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#drop-down-lists

I have this code:

```
<select name="category_id" class="form-control w-auto" required="required">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                                        <option value="{{ $category['id'] }}"
                                                @if(isset($product) && $product->category_id
                                                == $category['id']) selected="selected"
                                            @endif>{{ $category['name'] }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
```

I want change it to Laravel collective.

in $categories I have:

```
array:19 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "- Books"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "-- Comic Book"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
  8 => array:2 [▶]
  9 => array:2 [▶]
  10 => array:2 [▶]
  11 => array:2 [▶]
  12 => array:2 [▶]
  13 => array:2 [▶]
  14 => array:2 [▶]
  15 => array:2 [▶]
  16 => array:2 [▶]
  17 => array:2 [▶]
  18 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

(it's work fine).

Now in my blade i'm try make my select/option:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            {{Form::label('category_id', 'Kategoria produktu', ['class'=>'col-form-label text-left col-lg-3 col-sm-12'])}}
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
                                {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, data_get($product ?? 0, 'category_id') == '0', ['placeholder' => 'Wybierz kategorię', 'required' => 'required', 'class'=>'form-control w-autos']) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

In result I have this: https://ibb.co/0Qj4v7k (with collective) not correct select, and correct: https://ibb.co/HC2VCxz (without collective)

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [wrong format](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#drop-down-lists) for the data you're passing to the select method. It requires an array where the key represents the value attribute of the option tag and the value represents the text inside:

```
[
    1 => '- Books',
    2 => '-- Comic Book",
    // ...
]
```

You can easily generate this by using the [`pluck` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) on your `$categories` database collection:

```
$categories->pluck('name', 'id');
```